# For every complex $z$, $e^z \ne 0$

Tags: analysis

In Real and Complex Analysis, 3rd Edition, Walter Rudin advances the following:

[image]
[image]

How does $e^z \cdot e^{-z} = 1$ entail $(a)$?

Comment: If $e^z=0$ then you will have $0 \cdot e^{-z}=0$ which is absurd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there was a $z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $e^z=0$ we would have

$e^z\cdot e^{-z}=0\cdot e^{-z} \Rightarrow\\1=0$

which simply is not true.

*EDIT*

Another way to look at it is by using the form $e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)$

with $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

Thus $0=e^{x+iy}=e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)\Rightarrow \cos y=-i\sin y$

which cannot hold.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\forall z\in\mathbb{C}:0\cdot z=0$

Answer (score 1):

if $e^z$ assumed to be $0$ then it can not be $$e^z\cdot e^{-z}=1$$ (it would be zero)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see is a proof by contradiction. Assume there exists a complex number z for which $e^z=0$.Then $|e^z|=0$. Which implies for this z, $e^{\Re{z}}=0$. Which is not true for any real number $\Re{z}$. Hence proved.